# Find the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}-b}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Can someone help me solve this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}-b}$$

with $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Comment: Don't you rather mean $x\to0$ ?

Comment: that right sry for that

Comment: Well, then apply l'Hopital, what are you waiting for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using L'Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}-b}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+a}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+b}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+b}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+a}$$

Answer (score 2):

Without using L'Hopital, expand the root in a power series, to get:
$$\sqrt{x^2+a^2} -a = \frac{x^2}{2a}+O(x^4)$$
Leading to the limit of the ratio being $b/a$.

Answer (score 1):

No need for L'Hopital - we simply multiply and divide by the *conjugate* radical expression:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}-b}&=\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}-b}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+a}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+b}\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+b}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+a}
\\ &=\frac{x^2+a^2-a^2}{x^2+b^2-b^2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+b}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+a}=
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+b}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+a}\to\frac{2b}{2a}=\frac{b}{a}.
\end{align}